# What is the purpose of glClearDepth in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

It seems to be similar to the glClearColor function. glClearColor control what value gets written to the colour buffer, so does this mean that glClearDepth controls what value gets written to the depth buffer?

What would happen if it was given 0.5?
And when would this function be useful?

Comment: [Yes, it controls the depth clear value.](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClearDepth.xml) It's been a while since I last did anything particularly interesting in OpenGL, but I seem to recall that it can be useful if used in conjunction with the [stencil buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer) for achieving certain effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this mean that glClearDepth controls what value gets written to the depth buffer?

[Yes:](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClearDepth.xhtml)

> Description
>
> `glClearDepth` specifies the depth value used by `glClear` to clear the
>   depth buffer. Values specified by `glClearDepth` are clamped to the
>   range [0,1].

Don't forget you can use [other comparisons](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml) instead of just the default `GL_LESS`; `GL_EQUAL` in particular is useful for multi-pass Lighting rendering to prevent non-drawn fragments from being recalculated when they don't need to be.